# How to deserialize date in format "yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss"?

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-android-extensions, kotlin-multiplatform, date-parsing, kotlin-multiplatform-mobile

I am getting a date in a format like this "2021-03-26 22:02:53" from the API which is not ISO format, and I created a custom serializer for it but I am getting an error.
I also do not want to use ISO format, and I want to send back the date as "yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss".

Since We can not use Java.Date in Kotlin multiplatform, what is the proper solution to serialize date format like this?

[image: IDE with code file open]

[image: Debug frame variables]

Thanks

Comment: Please share some code, the error you are getting and the images properly.

Comment: Use the multi-platform date-time library. https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx-datetime

Comment: How to use it here? I can not use Date-formater since it is Java.library.

Comment: Please avoid posting images of code, this is not searchable and not accessible. Please copy the code into a code block instead (you can surround it with triple backticks)

Answer (score 2):

Currently, kotlinx-datetime only supports the ISO format.

However, the format you expect is close enough to ISO, so you could tweak it by simply replacing the space by a `T` and should be good to go. It's not ideal but it should do the job while waiting for proper formatting support from Kotlinx datetime.

```kotlin
return decoder.decodeString().replace(' ', 'T').toLocalDateTime()
```

You can also do the opposite when serializing:

```kotlin
encoder.encodeString(value.toString().replace('T', ' '))
```